# Working with caret in Text Formatter API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, text-editor, caret

I'm creating simple WPF text editor via [Text Formatter API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754036(v=vs.100).aspx). I've already done some of the basic functionality and now I need to add a caret support. I also have a visual caret (just a line with blinking animation) that should be synchronized with rendered text. I found a bunch of methods in [TextLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textline(v=vs.100).aspx) class, such as [GetNextCaretCharacterHit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textline.getnextcaretcharacterhit(v=vs.100).aspx) , [GetPreviousCaretCharacterHit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textline.getpreviouscaretcharacterhit(v=vs.100).aspx#United%20States%20(English)) , [GetBackspaceCaretCharacterHit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textline.getbackspacecaretcharacterhit(v=vs.100).aspx) . But the documentation information about them is ...quite scarce. Could somebody who has some experience in that field explain how to deal with these methods, because I have almost no idea about that?
I tried to search the information in the internet, but as a result I found nothing.

I would be grateful for any help!